# Why are no tests executed after migration from Play 2.2.2 to 2.3 with activator test?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3

I upgraded my application from Play 2.2.2 to 2.3. My app is running well.

Sometimes `activator test` gives the following output:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/myapp/project
[info] Set current project to myapp (in build file:/Users/myapp/)
[info] Compiling 23 Scala sources and 180 Java sources to /Users/myapp/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Compiling 55 Java sources to /Users/myapp/target/scala-2.10/test-classes...
[success] Total time: 112 s, completed 24 juin 2014 17:53:06
```

and that's it... No tests are run. If I try to run `testOnly`, it is not found.

Plus, even if I don't change any file, each time I try to test my app, the source are recompiled. That was not the case with Play 2.2.

I don't even have more logs to show. When I try to test with `activator ui` I have more logs but no test is run either.

If I delete manually the folders `project/project`, `project/target` and `target`, and run the command `activator test`, I get the following errors for every test class:

```
[error] Execution of test functional.actor.UserEditInformationTest failed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: functional.actor.UserEditInformationTest
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[error]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
[error]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
[error]     at com.novocode.junit.JUnitRunner$1.execute(JUnitRunner.java:120)
[error]     at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:294)
[error]     at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:284)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[info] functional.actor.UserEditInformationTest
[info] ! functional.actor.UserEditInformationTest
[error] sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: functional.actor.UserEditInformationTest
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[error]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
[error]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
```

How can I fix the issue?

**EDIT**
My `build.sbt` file :

```
name := "myapp"

version := "1.0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

offline := true

// Play Core dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    cache
)

// Specific dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    ...
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

jacoco.settings

parallelExecution in jacoco.Config := false

fork in Test := true

javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"

testOptions in jacoco.Config += Tests.Setup( () => System.setProperty("config.file", "conf/application.test.conf") )
```

Comment: Could you add an example test source and your build definition?

Comment: Do you know how can I export the full log of Activator UI ?

Comment: Nope, but you should be able to run `activator`, which should give you a console, and then type `test` there, and after all type `last` to get verbose logs

Comment: It appears JUnit is executed - see the line with `com.novocode.junit.JUnitRunner$1.execute(JUnitRunner.java:120)`. Do you have JUnit tests? What's your build configuration? Could you reproduce it with a smaller application?

Comment: Yes I tried to build a smaller application and I have no problem. But my project is bigger I think the compilation process is unstable with "lots of" classes to compile. I updated my question with my `build.sbt` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play 2.3.1 has been released : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/kz3iaBbPIwA

I upgraded my app and everything seems to work now. I can execute my tests as often as I want and they work.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem upgrading an application from Play 2.2.1 to 2.3.7. Somehow it seems that Eclipse is interfering. My personal solution is to quit Eclipse, and eventually quit the activator console too. Then I run

```
 activator clean
 activator cleanFiles
```

then

```
 activator test
```

or

```
 activator testOnly <package>.<testClass>
```

Sometimes it does not work at the fist attempt. When finally the activator finds (and runs) the tests, then everything works smoothly, and I can again turn on the activator console and Eclipse.

I hope this will help...

**Update**

Every time I write a new test class, `testOnly` does not find it. I need to run first the combination `clean` - `cleanFiles` to make `testOnly` find it (no necessity to turn off Eclipse in this case).

Comment: You're right. More info on this thread on Github : https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2904#issuecomment-46924670.

"Yeah, using the current version of sbteclipse causes massive pain because it causes eclipse to build the source and put the output in the same directory where sbt is trying to put class files. This issue and a few others that affect Play should all be fixed when sbteclipse 3.0.0 is released. Here's an issue to track the 3.0.0 release: typesafehub/sbteclipse#235"